# Store JSON output in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, cocoa, cocoa-touch

Good morning,

I'm trying to develop my first App and I'm using TableView in order to show my entries from a MySQL database and I'm having some trouble when I have to parse the JSON output.

I have already created the connection with my JSON, but now I need to save all the `id` in a single Array, all the `user` in another array, etc, etc. As you can see below in my second code, I need to store them in a `NSArray`. How can I do that?

**That's my JSON**

```
[{"id":"15","user":"1","imagen":"http:\/\/farmaventas.es\/images\/farmaventaslogo.png","date":"2014-09-13"}
,{"id":"16","user":"2","imagen":"http:\/\/revistavpc.es\/images\/vpclogo.png","date":"2014-11-11"}]
```

And that's my **TableViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
 NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
 NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 NSError * error;
 NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

  // Here I have to store my "user"
  self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

  // Here I have to store my "imagen"
  self.carModels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];
 }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you do.  You want to create a custom object which is initialised from those dictionaries (you can even provide an `initWithDictionary:` method in this custom object).

Comment: Thanks for both answers, can you explain it using my example? As I told you, I'm very new using JSON with xcode and I'm lost at the moment. Thanks again for your help @trojanfoe

Comment: @trojanfoe can't he use `[json valueForKeyPath:@"user"]`?

Comment: @Chinttu-Maddy-Ramani I was talking to the OP.  Using a separate array for each element in those dictionaries is not the way to go.

Comment: @trojanfoe oh yes. its not a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you would want to fetch JSON on another thread, so you dont block your main thread with it:

```
@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

    [self fetchJson];


}

-(void)fetchJson {
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://website.com/service.php"];
        NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSError * error;
        NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         // I advice that you make your carModels mutable array and initialise it here,before start working with json
         self.carModels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   @try {
        NSError *error;

        NSMutableArray* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                                JSONObjectWithData:theData
                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves
                                error:&error];

        if (error){
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

        }
        else{

            for(int i=0;i<json.count;i++){



                NSDictionary * jsonObject = [json objectAtIndex:i];

                NSString* imagen = [jsonObject objectForKey:@"imagen"];
                [carModel addObject:imagen];
            }

           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          // If you want to do anything after you're done loading json, do it here
         }

});
```

}

Comment: Thanks @SteBra. Is that "[carModel addObject:imagen];" going to be the same as: "self.carModels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];"? I need to be that way because I have already a DetailViewController with that values.

Comment: No, don't make an SNArray. Make NSMutableArray instead. If you hane NSArray, you have to put all the values in the array rith at initialisation time. With NSMutableArray, you can add items to an array at any time. That's better for you, since oyyou are adding 1 by 1 car model, as you read your JSON

Comment: OK, I'm going to use your way but then I have to know how can I send those values to my DetailViewController. Can you show me an example using that?

Comment: Yeah, sure. Make another question for that and I'll be glad to answer you :)

Comment: Thanks @SteBra, I'm going to post it later because at the moment I'm not able to reach my MAC. But I'm much appreciated for your help. Also I would like to know how I write your code in my TableViewController if you said that I have to put that code outside the main thread. How can I call it from my "main thread"?

Comment: write all this code in a method called -(void)parseJon for example. then, on wiewDidLoad simply call that method [self fetchJson] and the job will be done outside of the main thread, which leaves you room to do other stuff on the main thread..like showing a spinner with loading message or letting a user navigate back, if he wants to, or something third

Comment: Thanks again for your help @SteBra. Can you edit your answer and add that code? I will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to create another thread because I'm having problems with your code @SteBra.

Answer (score 1):

That's another solution with KVC

```
    NSArray *carMakes = [json valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.id"];
    NSArray *carModels = [json valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfObjects.user"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
// Here you have to store my "user"
self.userArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (NSDictionary *userInfo in json){
    //get "user" from json
    NSString* user = [userInfo objectForKey:@"user"];
    //add to array
    [userArray addObject:user];
}
```

You have use `NSMutableArray` to add object instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Vu Tuan Anh. How can I have that "user" in my self.carMakes? I want to be that way because I have already build a DetailViewController that display those values and I would like to have it that way. Is is possible?

Comment: If you have to use NSArray -> after for {} add the line: `self.carMakes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:self.userArray];`

Comment: I recommend that, in .h files, user declare `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray carMakes`. And in the above code, you could change `self.userArray` to `self.carMakes`

Answer (score 0):

Since "json" is array of NSDictionary you can get iterate over it and add to arrays like this:

```
    NSArray *json = @[@{@"id":@"15",@"user":@"1",@"imagen":@"http:\/\/farmaventas.es\/images\/farmaventaslogo.png",@"date":@"2014-09-13"},
                     @{@"id":@"16",@"user":@"2",@"imagen":@"http:\/\/revistavpc.es\/images\/vpclogo.png",@"date":@"2014-11-11"}];

    NSArray *carMakes = [NSArray array];
    NSArray *carModels = [NSArray array];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in json) {
        carMakes = [carMakes arrayByAddingObject:dict[@"id"]];
        carModels = [carModels arrayByAddingObject:dict[@"user"]];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",carMakes);
    NSLog(@"%@",carModels);
```

Comment: Is that *json the return values of my JSON output? Because you write it instead of recieve the data from http://www.website.com/service.php?

Comment: just a shourtcut :) this is what is produced with given json example.